# Create file request results in "Request had invalid authentication credentials", even though client id and secret are valid

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a folder in my drive using my Laravel APP. My Google drive credentials are correct but i keep getting this error:

> { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request had invalid
> authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login
> cookie or other valid authentication credential. See
> [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
> "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid Credentials", "domain": "global",
> "reason": "authError", "location": "Authorization", "locationType":
> "header" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }

Here is the Controller:

```
try {

        $client = new Client();
         $client->setApplicationName('MyAppTest');
         $client->setClientId(env('GOOGLE_APP_ID'));
         $client->setClientSecret(env('GOOGLE_APP_SECRET'));
         $client->setAccessToken(env('GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN'));
       // $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
        $driveService = new Drive($client);
        $fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile(array(
            'name' => 'Invoices',
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
        $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
            'fields' => 'id'));
        printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);
        return $file->id;

    }catch(Exception $e) {
       echo "Error Message: ".$e;
    }
```

Comment: Just for further clarification, could you please specifically share what type of credentials you are using? Is it an `API key`, an `OAuth Client ID`, or a `Service account`?

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 It’s an OAuth Client ID

Comment: using the same credentials, can you do anything else? upload, delete, rename, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not requesting access of the user, all you have done is created the client and then you are making a request to the api.  The call wont be authorized unless you request consent of a user.

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly');
    $client->setAuthConfig('C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1");
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {

            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token, or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
try {
    $client = getClient();
}
catch(Exception $e) {

    unlink("token.json");
    $client = getClient();
    }

$service = new Drive($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
try{


    $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'fields' => 'files(id,name,mimeType)',
        'q' => 'mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" and "root" in parents',
        'orderBy' => 'name'
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    $files = $results->getFiles();

    if (empty($files)) {
        print "No files found.\n";
    } else {
        print "Files:\n";
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $id = $file->id;

            printf("%s - (%s) - (%s)\n", $file->getId(), $file->getName(), $file->getMimeType());
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```